# jQuery hover menu on embedded list items

Tags: jquery

Struggling to understand this. Apologies for stupidity.

I have a menu that looks like this - not my choice of format, it's automatically generated from WordPress:

***CSS***

```
​.menu_body {
    display: none;   
}​
```

***HTML***

```
<ul id="menu-list">
    <li class="menu_head"><a href="#">Header-1</a></li>
    <li class="menu_head"><a href="#">Header-2</a>
    <ul class="menu_body">
        <li><a href="#">Link-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link-2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_head"><a href="#">Header-3</a>
    <ul class="menu_body">
        <li><a href="#">Link-3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link-4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_head"><a href="#">Header-4</a></li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

What I'm trying to do is write a jQuery hover based function that, on hovering over an item with class menu_head, shows the items in the class "menu_body" beneath it.

From somewhere else I picked up the idea that it's neat and tidy to use a function that will open one menu and *close all the others* as it does so. It would look something like this:

```
$("#menu-list li.menu_head").mouseover(function()
{
 $(this).children('.menu_body').slideDown(500).siblings(".menu_body").slideUp("slow");

});​
```

That doesn't work but you can see what I'm trying to do - get the first related 'menu_body' item and slide it down and then get all the other 'menu_body' items and slide them up.

You can see an example of this with DIVs here (which is where I stole the idea from):

**[Example link](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/06/accordion-menu-using-jquery.html)**

But struggling hugely to make it work with nested divs.

Can someone suggest what I need to do, and explain so I can understand what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YFLjU/)

```
$("#menu-list li.menu_head").mouseover(function() {
    $(".menu_body").stop().slideUp("slow");
    $(this).children('.menu_body').delay(600).stop().slideDown(500);
});
```

Your `.menu_body` items aren't siblings to each other.

Comment: Tried this. It's very flaky. Not sure why but menus will stop opening half way and then refuse to open unless is the page is refreshed and other oddities.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a mouseOver and mouseLeave.

```
$("#menu-list li.menu_head").mouseOver(function() {
    $(this).children('.menu_body').slideDown(500);
});
$("#menu-list li.menu_head").mouseLeave(function() {
    $(this).children('.menu_body').stop().slideUp(500);
});
```

Otherwise if you don't scroll to another menu element, lets say to the content below, your slide up might not get called correctly.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jZWgm/1/)

​

Comment: bad : if you hover over Header 3 in a weird way, say you are inside header 2, hover over header 3 and come back to a child of header 2 before it is fully collapsed, you get a a cyclic behaviour. Little chance of it, but I actually discovered it accidentally.

Comment: Should just need to add a stop(), that seems to fix the issue. Wasn't thinking of that at the time, good catch.

Comment: Add a stop where? I've implemented this and it seems to work pretty well but I think I keep catching the mentioned behaviour. Also after a few scrolls the whole thing seems to lock down :(

Comment: I updated the example to include stop(), its in the mouseLeave function. My example seems to be fine, having slideUp / Down in a list sometimes has issues by nature. Hopefully this is still useful to you.  I wasn't sure if you wanted the nav to stay open, if thats the intent then I think one of the other suggestions may be what your after

Comment: Ah right. Here it is on an actual website and - as you'll see if you play about with it - it just seems to sieze up after a few passes. I find JQuery terribly frustrating. http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay between animations, like so:

```
$(this).children('.menu_body').slideDown(500).delay(500).siblings(".menu_body").slideUp("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt, try using defereds.

something like the following might help as a starting block.

```
$.when($('div').animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1000)).done(function(){
    // divs hidden, run code to show them
    $('div').animate({"opacity": "100"}, 1000)
});
```